# I can't concatenate ssh to a server from another server

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting

I want to get the last folders name from a pi and this commands works just fine:

`ssh pi@192.168.6.24 'ls -t /media/usb/Pictures/new/ | head -1'`

Returns: 230125_1356

To retrieve the number of files in that folder I'm using:

`ssh pi@192.168.6.24 ls -t /media/usb/Pictures/new/$(ssh pi@192.168.6.24 'ls -t /media/usb/Pictures/new/ | head -1')/ | wc -l`

Returns: 5

But now I'm trying to get the same results from another pi connected to the first one:
This one works fine and gives me the name of the last folder:

`ssh -t pi@192.168.6.24 ssh pi@192.168.0.50 'ls -t /media/usb/Pictures/new/ | head -1'`

Returns: 230125_1356

My problem arises when I try to get the number of files inside the last folder over the second pi with:

`ssh -t pi@192.168.6.24 ssh pi@192.168.0.50 ls -t /media/usb/Pictures/new/$(ssh -t pi@192.168.6.24 ssh pi@192.168.0.50 ls -t /media/usb/Pictures/new/ | head -1)/ | wc -l`

Returns: 1

The return should be 4 which is the number of files in that folder.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Consider using something like `sshfs` if you do this a lot. [Parsing the output of `ls` should be avoided.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: Thanks Panki for your answer, I've tried this command and it doesn't work, I can't see the mounted filesystem in the mounted point.
```sudo sshfs -o sshfs_debug  laptop@192.168.6.89:/ /mnt/field_laptop```

SSHFS version 2.10.0
laptop@192.168.6.89's password: 
Server version: 3
Extension: posix-rename@openssh.com <1>
Extension: statvfs@openssh.com <2>
Extension: fstatvfs@openssh.com <2>
Extension: hardlink@openssh.com <1>
Extension: fsync@openssh.com <1>